# Django Razorpay integration working on test server but This payment has already been captured error in live session

Tags: python, django, razorpay

I'm first time to use razorpay live mode, transaction is sucessful but get error Payment has already been captured.The payment collection works fine but when it comes to verifying the payment it seems to break on the live server. The order amount and details sent to razorpay seem to be working fine but response capture is maybe breaking. Below is my copy of views.py

```
def process_booking_payment(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST":
        params = request.POST

        razorpay_order_id = params.get('razorpay_order_id')
        razorpay_payment_id = params.get('razorpay_payment_id')
        razor_signature = params.get('razorpay_signature')
        MD = MasterData.objects.get()
        RAZORPAY_CLIENT = razorpay.Client(auth=(MD.razorpay_key, MD.razorpay_secret))
        RAZORPAY_CLIENT.set_app_details({"title": MD.company_name, "version": "1.0"})
        params_dict={
                'razorpay_order_id': razorpay_order_id,
                'razorpay_payment_id': razorpay_payment_id,
                'razorpay_signature': razor_signature
            }
        bookin = get_object_or_404(Booking,payment_id = kwargs.get('payment_id'),
                                       razorpay_order_id=razorpay_order_id)
            
        bookin.razorpay_payment_id = razorpay_payment_id
        bookin.razorpay_signature = razor_signature
        bookin.save()
        RAZORPAY_CLIENT.utility.verify_payment_signature(params_dict)
        try:                
            with transaction.atomic():
                rp_capture = RAZORPAY_CLIENT.payment.capture(
                    razorpay_payment_id,float(bookin.booked_amount * 100)
                )
                    
                bookin.payment_status = '1'
                    
                confirm = create_booking(request,payment_id = bookin.payment_id)
                if 'errorDetails' in confirm:
                    bookin.booking_status = '6'
                else:
                    bookin.booking_status = '2'
                    bookin.booking_details.is_confirmed = True
                    bookin.booking_details.save()
                bookin.save()
                    
                messages.success(request, 'Payment Successful')
                log = LOG.objects.create(
                    user = request.user,
                    function = 'payment',
                    response = 'payment success'
                )
                log.save()
                return JsonResponse({
                    'success': True,
                    'redirect_to': reverse('my-booking',args=[request.user.slug])
                })
        except Exception as e:
            bookin.booking_status = '6'
            bookin.payment_status = '2'
            bookin.save()
            print(e)
            log = LOG.objects.create(
                user = request.user,
                function = 'payment',
                response = e
            )
            log.save()
            return JsonResponse({
                'success': False,
                'redirect_to': '',
                'msg':'eroror',
                "error_url":reverse('my-booking',args=[request.user.slug])
            })
```